# Switching between layouts in android

Tags: android, layout

In my layout file - main.xml(linear layout), there are 2 buttons(say b1 and b2), 1 listview and 1 relative layout. When I click on b1, list view is made `VISIBLE` and the relative layout is made `GONE`. When I click on b2, listview is made `GONE` and relative layout is made `VISIBLE`. Here is the code,

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
           public void onClick(View v)
           {
               try{ListView listView = (ListView) Home.this.findViewById(R.id.mylist);
                listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

                String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
                    "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
                    "Linux", "OS/2" ,"asdsad","asdsdsa","asdasdsa"};
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
                        R.layout.list_item,values);

                    // Assign adapter to ListView
                RelativeLayout rl=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl1);
                rl.setVisibility(8);
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    listView.setVisibility(0);}
               catch(Exception e){Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
           }

       });<br>
b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
           public void onClick(View v)
           {
            try
            {

            ListView ls=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist);
            ls.setVisibility(8);
            RelativeLayout rl=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl1);
            getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.creategroup,rl,true);
            rl.setVisibility(0);


            EditText username=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.group_owner_fill);
            username.setText(userid);
            username.setEnabled(false);
            username.setFocusable(false);
            boolean t=username.isEnabled();
            String s=new Boolean(t).toString();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
           }

       });
```

First time when I click b2, the Edittext(username) is locked(i.e setenabled and setfocussable are made false). But when I click b1 and then click b2, the Edittext is not locked and also setText is not there. What can be the possible reason for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of setting visibility, i would suggest you to implement [ViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html). Because ViewFlipper allows us to flip views whenever user want.

```
 <ViewFlipper
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/flip">

    <ListView />
        <RelativeLayout>
        .............
        .............
        .............         
        </RelativeLayout>

</ViewFlipper>
```

In code, you can flip the view by using setDisplayedChild() method. FYI, RelativeLayout is the child 1. so you have to write down `flipper.setDisplayedChild(1)`

Comment: @user370305 yes i know, actually i was creating layout code example inside the eclipse code editor :)

Comment: @PareshMayani : Suraj has asked for a possible reason for the output that he is getting.

Comment: @PareshMayani paresh bhai! Can you tell me the reason for why my code is not working porperly? I mean the layouts are switching but Edittext is not getting disabled for the 2nd time i click on b2